# What is $[L:M]$ and $[L:Q]$

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $M = Q(\sqrt{1+\sqrt{7}})$. $L = Q(\sqrt{1+\sqrt{7}},\sqrt{1-\sqrt{7}})$. What is $[L:M]$ and $[L:Q]$.

I know I can use tower rule for $[L:Q]$. And I know $[L:M]$ is 2. Can anyone help what is $[L:Q]$? I don't know how to approach. Thanks!

Comment: Hint: $\sqrt{1+\sqrt7}$ has inverse $\sqrt{\sqrt7-1}/\sqrt6$.

Comment: Well, not really hinting in the correct direction :(

Comment: Hint: you have to compute $[M:\mathbb Q]$. It will be easier to introduce $K=\mathbb Q(\sqrt{7})$ and compute $[M:K]$ and $[K:\mathbb Q]$.

Comment: @Wojowu Thanks for the hint. [:ℚ] is pretty straightforward. However, I am not sure about [:]

Comment: $[M:K]$ is clearly of degree at most $2$, and it's equal to $2$ iff $1+\sqrt{7}$ is not a square in $K$. Now observe that if $1+\sqrt{7}$ were a square, so would $1-\sqrt{7}$.

Comment: @Wojowu Thanks for replying! I think it is the opposite right? That is, degree is 2 iff 1+√7 is a square in K. So [:] is 2?

Comment: No, what I wrote is correct. If $1+\sqrt{7}$ were a square, then we would have $M=K$ and $[M:K]=1$. So we have to show $1+\sqrt{7}$ is not a square in $\mathbb Q(\sqrt{7})$.

Comment: @Wojowu I see! Thanks so much!